# Liquibase Rollback and Update errors

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, liquibase

I have been assigned a team currently using liquibase to version their database and being new to the environment a problem came about from the developers and wanted to find what would be the best practice. I have never worked with liquibase before this, so bare with what I am trying to ask. The issue being is that developers are adding unintended changes(spaces or new lines) to a liquibase script inside the repo and not noiced and pushing their changes and liquibase is seeing it as a change. This was an example one of the developers gave me. Which I know can be dumb especially making sure the developers should be paying attention and git has ways of preventing this, but was given the task to create a some way to rollback if this issue were to arise. I was wondering if creating a rollback procedure is the best way or some way implment a block to not allow things like this to happen and if so what? Would it be on the db side as a block of is there something in liquibase that can prevent this. Also, being I think having a rollback procedure import for those one off accidents, whats the best way to create one for liquibase? As in best practice for a production level environment.

Comment: Spaces or newlines should not (imho) not lead to liquibase thinking that there are changes. If so, please share an example. Also, developers (again imho) should avoid adding spaces and newlines to otherwise untouched files. Rollback is surely a nice concept but not a solution for unwanted changes of this kind.

Comment: I couldnt see an example, which also made me thing that wasnt the case, the issue was I was still given a task to create a rollback procedure, but was looking also to see what and why these things were happening but the more I read and find out makes me think thats not the case. Thank you for your response.